# Convolution of two bernoulli distributions

Tags: convolution

Find the probability mass function of the sum of X ∼ Bernoulli(p) and an independent Y ∼ Bernoulli(q) variable.

I started by letting Z=X+Y

So $$P_z(Z)= \sum_{i=0}^{1}f_x(x) f_y(z-x) $$

$$ \sum_{i=0}^{1}\dbinom{1}{x} p^{x}(1-p)^{1-x}  \dbinom{1}{z-x} q^{z-x}(1-q)^{1-z+x} $$
I am unsure as to how I can evaluate this

Thankyou for your help